# Replicating restricted s.level from rucm in Python's statsmodels

Tags: python, r, time-series, statsmodels

I've created a Unobserved Components Model in R using the [rucm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rucm/rucm.pdf) package:

```
# input regression formula and extract x and y variables
regression_formula <- as.formula(paste("WebsiteVisits ~ MarketingSpend"))  

target_var <- formula.tools::lhs(regression_formula)
fo <-
  as.formula(paste(formula.tools::lhs.vars(regression_formula), " ~ ", paste(
    formula.tools::rhs.vars(regression_formula), collapse = " + "
  )))

# build unrestricted UCM
unrestricted_mod <- ucm(
  fo,
  data = final_data,
  level = TRUE,
  slope = TRUE,
  season = FALSE,
)

# build restricted UCM
restricted_mod <- ucm(
  fo,
  data = final_data,
  level = TRUE,
  level.var = .1 * mean(unrestricted_mod$vs.level),
  slope = TRUE,
  season = FALSE,
)

restricted_mod$s.level
```

How can I recreate this (i.e. get the exact same s.level values using the same parameters) using [UnobservedComponents](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.structural.UnobservedComponents.html) from Python's statsmodels?

Current progress:

```
unrestricted_mod = UnobservedComponents(final_data['WebsiteVisits'], exog=final_data['MarketingSpend'], level=True, slope=True, seasonal=False)
unrestricted_mod.fit().summary()

# average of the unrestricted model's level (unsure if this is the same as vs.level in R)
np.mean(unrestricted_mod.fit().level['filtered'])

# now I need to input that value in a restricted model

# ...but I can't seem to input a value here for stochastic_level, only boolean
restricted_mod = UnobservedComponents(final_data['WebsiteVisits'], exog=final_data['MarketingSpend'], level = True, stochastic_level = True, slope=True, seasonal=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
unrestricted_mod = UnobservedComponents(final_data['WebsiteVisits'], exog=final_data['MarketingSpend'], trend = True, stochastic_trend = True, irregular = True, level=True, stochastic_level = True, slope = True, seasonal = False)
print(unrestricted_mod.param_names)

with unrestricted_mod.fix_params({'sigma2.level': .1 * np.mean(unrestricted_mod.fit().level['smoothed'])}):
    restricted_mod = unrestricted_mod.fit()
    
restricted_mod.summary()
```

The key is 1. making sure the parameters match (note that irregular's default is False in Python and True in R) and 2. using `fix_params` to set the level for the restricted model.

My coefficients match up pretty closely between Python and R, but not exactly. I don't know if this is just unfixable and due to difference in calculations, or I'm missing something in my code; I don't think there's another parameter I should fix.